# Remapping a pair of 2D points to another pair of points

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, plane-geometry

I have been working on the following problem for a while, but I am not making any headway:

Given two points in a view A (ax,ay) and B (bx,by), transform them so that they are positioned at C (cx,cy) and D (dx,dy) respectively.  *Additionally, since this is for presentation/image processing, the resulting complete transformation must be proportional and not reflected.*

Specifically what I want is to directly calculate the *single* transformation matrix M that can make this change in one step and without using any trigonometric functions, if possible. In other words:

```
M:               A:     C:
| xx  yx  wx |   |ax|   |cx|
| xy  yy  wy | * |ay| = |cy|
| 0   0   1  |   | 1|   | 1|
```

And

```
M:               B:     D:
| xx  yx  wx |   |bx|   |dx|
| xy  yy  wy | * |by| = |dy|
| 0   0   1  |   | 1|   | 1|
```

And I want to directly calculate the values of the matrix M.

Now I know that it could be accomplished with the following standard transforms:

1. Translate B to the origin:  T(-bx,-by)
2. Counter-rotate the slope B-A to zero.
3. Rotate to the slope D-C.
4. Scale distance ||A-B|| to distance ||C-D||: (i.e. ||C-D||/||A-B||)
5. Translate from origin to D.

Or, in transform shorthand:

1. T(-bx,-by)
2. R(-s(B:A))
3. R(s(D:C))
4. S(|C-D|/|A-B|)
5. T(dx,dy)

However, I am using this in a real-time program to present two different dynamic POVs and the overhead of 5 transforms is pretty significant.  I also know that I can combine steps 2 and 3, but that would require additional trig functions and trig functions also have a lot of overhead for a real-time display.

Finally, the source points A and B are moving dynamically in the original POV so I cannot just combine all of the steps into one static transform matrix and reuse that  (I am actually dynamically remapping the entire view to the second viewport, the GUI will do it for me, if I can supply it with the transform matrix).

I have been trying to derive the calculations by symbolically combining the transformation arrays, or alternatively trying to solve the simultaneous equations using equivalences and proportionality principles but the terms and radicals start to explode and exceed my manual limits pretty quickly.  I have been able to avoid the trig functions using slopes and Pythagorean equivalences instead, but that has meant that I end up with a lot of nested expressions with radicals and also the loss of signs that comes with both radicals and slopes.  So at this point I think I need some help.

I can supply what I have so far on either approach, but they’re pretty far into the weeds and I’m hoping that this is some standard operation that has a known solution (it’s certainly seems like it would come up a lot).  I looked at this question [Remapping plane parameters for a different Cartesian system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2699998/remapping-plane-parameters-for-a-different-cartesian-system) which seemed related, but I didn't understand the question or the answer well enough to reapply it.

Bonus question:  Does this operation have a standard name?  I have been calling it "Remapping", but that seems pretty generic and search for that doesn't results in anything specific to this.

Also: I don’t know Tex, etc. so anyone who wants the Editor points can edit my post to make it look better symbolically.

---

I have updated the text above with:

*Additionally, since this is for presentation/image processing, the resulting complete transformation must be proportional and not reflected.*

Comment: You have 4 equations and 6 variables, meaning there are infinite answers. Are there other conditions on $M$ ?

Comment: As you are asking for names, two keywords that can help you to find your way through the maze : "epipolar geometry", "fundamental matrix" (https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/hzbook2/HZepipolar.pdf).

Comment: @Exodd My hope is that someone else more knowledgeable in homogeneous coordinates and transformation matrices would know the answer to that.  The transformation steps lead to a definite result, so it has to be possible to find some solution(s).  My assumption has been that what's missing is proportionality and non-reflection constraints.  I *think* that proportionality can be expressed as `xx^2+xy^2 = yx^2+yy^2` and also `xx^2+yx^2 = xy^2+yy^2` (which I think means that `|xy| = |yx|` and `|xx| = |yy|`).  Not sure about constraining reflection, that might be done with the signs of these.

Comment: @RBarryYoung If you put $wx$ and $wy$ to zero, you just have to invert a matrix

Comment: @Exodd I am not adept at matrix manipulation, but *wx* and *wy* cannot be zero unless {A,B} and {C,D} are the same points.  The only way to accomplish the Translation steps with matrix multiplication is by setting them to the *x* and *y* differences of the source and target points in homogeneous coordinates.

Comment: @RBarryYoung You are asking for *one* solution. The 5-steps you wrote provides a specific solution, but it is not the only one. $wx$ and $wy$ can be zero. In fact you can bring A,B into C,D without translations in almost all cases.

Comment: @Exodd While retaining proportionality and without reflections?  If so, please demonstrate, I would be most interested.  if you want an example try A=(-9,-7), B=(-8,-6), C=(10,-1) and D=(-1,10).

Comment: @RBarryYoung nono, obviously you use reflections and probably do not retain proportionality

Comment: @Exodd, that is a requirement.  The resulting image has to be non-distorted (proportional) and not be reflected at the end.  I will update the question to make this clear.  AFAIK the combined transformation matrix should give the only solution (though I am not 100% certain)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$\left[ \begin{matrix} x_x & y_x & t_x \\ x_y & y_y & t_y \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right ] \left [ \begin{matrix} a_x \\ a_y \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right ] = \left [ \begin{matrix} c_x \\ c_y \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right ]$$
is exactly equivalent to
$$\left[ \begin{matrix} x_x & y_x \\ x_y & y_y \end{matrix} \right ] \left [ \begin{matrix} a_x \\ a_y \end{matrix} \right ] + \left[ \begin{matrix} t_x \\ t_y \end{matrix} \right ] = \left [ \begin{matrix} c_x \\ c_y \end{matrix} \right ]$$

A pure 2D rotation matrix by counterclockwise angle $\theta$ is
$$\mathbf{R}_\theta = \left [ \begin{matrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{matrix} \right ]$$
So, if we write $\mathbf{R}$ as say
$$\mathbf{R} = \left [ \begin{matrix} c & -s \\ s & c \end{matrix} \right ]$$
we have four equations in four unknowns ($c$, $s$, $t_x$, and $t_y$):
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
c a_x - s a_y + t_x &= c_x \\
s a_x + c a_y + t_y &= c_y \\
c b_x - s b_y + t_x &= d_x \\
s b_x + c b_y + t_y &= d_y \\
\end{aligned} \right.$$
This has exactly one solution, if and only if
$$\Delta = (b_x - a_x)^2 + (b_y - a_y)^2 \ne 0$$
or in other words, iff points $A$ and $B$ differ.

---

To minimize numerical error, I would suggest calculating
$$\begin{aligned}
\Delta &= (b_x - a_x)^2 + (b_y - a_y)^2 \\
C &= (b_y - a_y)(d_y - c_y) + (b_x - a_x)(d_x - c_x) \\
S &= (b_x - a_x)(d_y - c_y) - (b_y - a_y)(d_x - c_x) \\
\end{aligned}$$
Note that $S^2 + C^2 = 0$ if and only if points $C$ and $D$ are the same, and/or points $A$ and $B$ are the same.

Then, the solution (rotation and scaling, but not skewing or mirroring) for $c$ and $s$ is
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
c &= \displaystyle \frac{C}{\Delta} \\
s &= \displaystyle \frac{S}{\Delta} \\
\end{aligned} \right .$$

If you require a pure rotation solution, without scaling, use
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
s &= \displaystyle \frac{S}{S^2 + C^2} \\
c &= \displaystyle \frac{C}{S^2 + C^2} \\
\end{aligned} \right .$$

If you are interested in the angle of rotation $\theta$, you can use
$$\left\lbrace ~\begin{aligned}
\theta &= \operatorname{atan2}(S, C) \\
s &= \cos\theta \\
c &= \sin\theta \\
\end{aligned} \right.$$

After calculating $s$ and $c$, again in an effort to keep numerical errors to a minimum,
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
t_x &= \displaystyle \frac{ c_x + d_x + s (a_y + b_y) - c (a_x + b_x) }{2} \\
t_y &= \displaystyle \frac{ c_y + d_y - c (a_y + b_y) - s (a_x + b_x) }{2} \\
\end{aligned}\right.$$

Because the form I used is equivalent to OP's, the single 2×3 transformation matrix sought for is
$$\mathbf{M} = \left [ \begin{matrix} c & -s & t_x \\ s & c & t_y \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right ]$$

Comment: Thanks, this looks very promising!  I will test it out tonight or tomorrow morning and let you know.

Comment: Do C and S represent anything(I need to give them different names in the code, because C and s are already in use)?  They're clearly some kind of slope differencing, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong, first there are two different formula for c and s with different results.  Secondly, the calculations are not working out for either.  When I use your the first method on {A=(0,1),B=(3,2), C=(3,4),D=(7,5)}, I get c=-.09, s=-.01, tx=5.123, ty=4.648.  When I apply MxA I get ( 5.13,4.56) for C instead of (3,4), and MxB gives (4.487,4.44) for D instead of (7,5). ...(more)...

Comment: ... Likewise, if I use the second method, I get c=-1.1, s=-.01, tx=6.5, ty=6.3.  When I apply MxA I get (6.6,5.2) for C instead of (3,4), and MxB gives (3.4,3.8) for D instead of (7,5).

Comment: The problem seems to be in the calculation of `c`.  When I use your first method, your 's' matches my numerical solution (-0.1), but I get 1.3 for `c` whereas I get -1.1 for your formula.  If I paste in 1.3 for `c` in your equations, then `tx` and `ty` and the final results of multiplying by M all work out correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I said your first method, but it's actually your second method that all works excpet for the calculation of `c`.

Comment: OK, your second method appears to work if you change the calculation of `C` to `C = ((by-ay)(dy-cy) + (by-ay)(dy-cy))` (changed the minus to a plus). If you can confirm that this is correct and update your solution, then I can mark it as the answer and award you the points.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: Oops!  Yes, I had miscopied the solution for $C$ from Maxima; I edited the answer, to reflect the correct $C$: $C = (b_y - a_y)(d_y - c_y) + (b_x - a_x)(d_x - c_x)$, i.e. only a sign change. (Note you listed `C = (by-ay)(dy-cy) + (by-ay)(dy-cy)` which is `C = 2(by-ay)(dy-cy)` yourself!  It is too easy to make these copy-paste errors.. :))   I also edited the second part a bit, hopefully to explain the relationship between $C$, $S$, $c$, and $s$ ($C = \Delta c$, $S = \Delta s$).